# Sorting with key not working

Tags: linux, unix, sorting, terminal

I am trying to sort entries that look like this, just formatted text data corresponding with  a region, using astronomical coordinates and names for those regions. I want to organize these regions based off their names which is inside the curly bracket.

circle(20:34:36.717,+40:51:51.90,15") # text={tadpole4h}

circle(20:25:28.500,+41:08:20.80,15") # text={tadpole33}

circle(20:32:40.867,+41:51:25.24,15") # text={tadpole45}

based on the numbers following the tadpole field
I'm relatively new to linux but thought I had this down from looking at other stack questions.
this was my crack at it:

```
sort -k54,56 -n test.reg
```

and

```
sort -k54,55 -n < test.reg
```

and

```
sort -k55,57 -n < test.reg
```

and

```
sort -k55,56 -n < test.reg
```

also tried it with k and n swapped and spelling out fully each part.
Another way I was thinking of searching it would be if i could just use wild cards to reach the tadpole string and then sort from there, but I couldnt figure out how to get wildcards working for sort.

Comment: also tried it with n and k swapped

Comment: Wow, you have more than 57 columns separated by spaces ? oO

Comment: You are sorting.  Now are you having some kind of problem that you would like to ask a question about?

Comment: What does `4h` mean? Is this hex? What order are you expecting? You haven't really said what the problem is.

Comment: ah, so k corrsponds to space seperations, i thought it meant a column in the text

Comment: you need to specify the "field" number, then the character offset inside that field. So I think you can say `-k1.55 -k1.56` (maybe a `+` is required for the 2nd value instead of `-`. check with `man sort`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed to prefix each line with the tadpole number, then sort your lines on this prefix, for the .* thing you are thinking:

```
sed 's/.*tadpole\([^}]*\)}/\1 &/' test.reg | sort -t' ' -k1
```

You can also remove the prefixes before printing:

```
sed 's/.*tadpole\([^}]*\)}/\1 &/' test.reg | sort -t' ' -k1 | sed 's/^[^ ]* //'
```